# ReactCssTransitionGroup, tuning down opacity and then slide it up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Hi dear stackOverFlow friends!

My question for the day is:
I have a header that is wrapped in a ReactCssTransitionGroup tag,
right now I'm tuning the opacity down and sliding it up at the same time, but I want to tune down the opacity to 0 and then slide it up so it doesn't show.

Here is my code now:

**CSS**:

```
.headTransition-enter {
    opacity: 0.01;
    height: 0px;
}

.headTransition-enter.headTransition-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 500ms ease-in;
    height: 520px;
}

.headTransition-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 520px;
}

.headTransition-leave.headTransition-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: 500ms ease-in;
    height: 0px;
}
```

**the component**:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
     transitionName="headTransition"
     transitionEnterTimeout={500}
     transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
          {!this.props.tabClicked && <Header/>}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

***Very grateful for answers!***